# Swift closures with delegates

Tags: swift, delegates, closures

So I am trying to create a closure when I receive something from a delegate method:

```
typealias CompletionResponse = ((_ response: AnyObject) -> Void)?

class SomeClass {

    static let shared = SomeClass()

    var completion: CompletionResponse?

    func getSomthing(completion: CompletionResponse) {
        self.completion = completion
    }

    func someDelegateMethode(info: [String]) {
        // Error is here
        if let completion = self.completion {
            completion(info)
        }
    }
}

 _ = SomeClass.shared

SomeClass.shared

SomeClass.shared.getSomthing { (obj) in
    print(obj as! [String])
}

SomeClass.shared.someDelegateMethod(info: ["Hello", "There"])
```

I am not sure how to do that.. 
I appreciate any help.

Error received :
**Cannot call value of non-function type 'CompletionResponse' (aka 'Optional<(AnyObject) -> ()>')**

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Remove the optional from the typealias.  The compiler doesn't understand how to call `completion` since it has a double optional type.

Additionally, you can use optional chaining rather than an `if let`.

`self.completion?(info)`

Comment: You have a nested optional. The `typealias` is already an optional type. Next, your `completion` property is declared as an optional. So you have two levels of optional to get through.

Comment: Your typealias is optional, and you also declaring `var completion` as optional.  The compiler doesn't understand how to call a function with a double optional.  In most cases, you only need a `?` on actual variable declarations rather than their typealiases.

Comment: So there are a few solutions - change the declaration of `completion` to `var completion: CompletionResponse`, remove the `?` from the `typealias` or unwrap `completion` twice.

Comment: Based on the code snippet I don't see a reason for the `typealias` to include optional.  All it does is restrict the type by forcing you to always have an optional.  Also double unwrap is evil. :)

Comment: Agreed. I would go with the first solution as well.

Comment: You guys are so right! Thanks for the quick notice and help.

Comment: @Samah I wouldn't discredit nested optionals. They're usually not intentional, but there are certainly times when they make sense. E.g. what should be the return type of `first` on an `Array<Optional<T>>`? If it were `T?`, how could we know if the `nil` we would get when the array is empty, vs the `nil` we would get when the first element is present, but is `nil` itself.

Comment: @EhabSaifan Please don't forget to indicate when one of your questions has been answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of the best answer to the question.

Comment: @Alexander fair point, but if that were the case I would probably write it another way.  In your example, checking `isEmpty` first would be a cleaner and safer solution.

Comment: @Samah How is that cleaner an safer? Rather than just conditionally unwrapping `first`, you would first be doing an `isEmpty` check, and force unwrapping `first`. No bueno

Answer (score 1):

Your `typealias CompletionResponse` is `Optional` and your completion attribute is also `Optional`. When you print the type of `completion`, you can see that it is a double `Optional`:

```
print(type(of: self.completion)) //Optional<Optional<(AnyObject) -> ()>>
```

What you want to do is call your `completion` function. However, since it is wrapped inside an `Optional`, you're telling the compiler to call a function on your `enum Optional`. Enums are not function-types and cannot be called and that is what the error is trying to tell you.

Now, there are multiple ways to solve your problem.

1. The solution that makes the most sense to me is remove the `Optional` type from your `typealias CompletionResponse`.

   `typealias CompletionResponse = (_ response: AnyObject) -> Void`

   `if let completion = self.completion {
       completion(info as AnyObject)
   }`

   or as a one-liner `self.completion?(info as AnyObject)`
2. You can also keep the double `Optional` and unwrap using `if let`

   `if let completion = self.completion.flatMap({ $0 }) {
       completion(info as AnyObject)
   }`

   or as a one-liner `self.completion??(info as AnyObject)`

Note that you have to specify `info as AnyObject`, otherwise you get another compiler error.

Comment: You are right! and this what @Nathan Hitchings and samah suggested as well. Thanks for all